# How to display a message/picture alert if there is no internet connection (PhoneGap)?

Tags: cordova, wifi, alert

**Problems (PhoneGap):**

1. How to display a message/picture alert if there is no internet
   connection?
2. How to prevent user to use/fully open the application after the alert (quit the
   application and display alerts later until user connects to the
   Internet)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, I tried listening to the "offline" event but apparently this did not work for me as well as it does not quit the program.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481939/how-to-alert-the-user-when-theres-no-internet-connection

Comment: note that you can only set the event-listener after the deviceready event fired
`function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

There's Phonegap documentation on this [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection). It discusses creating an 'alert' for various connection states.

I don't have much experience on platforms other than Android, but if you use the Phonegap [database feature](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage), data storage is persistant within a table if the app is 'force closed' or simply suspended.

To achieve what you're looking for, I would create a very simple table with a boolean value corresponding to whether there is network availability, which is updated through a function call based around [timed javascript functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170923/whats-the-easiest-way-to-call-a-function-every-5-seconds-in-jquery). A simple `if(){}` statement can then check the database value and either limit or enable functionality in the app.

Depending on how persistant you want the data to be, you could also do away with the database and just make a timed call to return the network status.