# How to alert the user if his internet connection is down

Tags: javascript, android

I'm developing an android app using HTML & JS, (will use PhoneGap after successful development) and I want the app to alert the user if his device is not connected to WiFi or Mobile data, and the app should close after the alert.

I tried this for reference:
[How to alert the user when there's no internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481939/how-to-alert-the-user-when-theres-no-internet-connection)

However, it doesn't seem to work for me.. Please suggest some other alternative for the same.

Comment: you can call ajax for "www.google.com", if ok, then the user probably has internet connection.

Comment: @DanielCheung Unfortunately I have no experience in Ajax.. Can you plz give me the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377579/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-phonegap-periodically

Answer (score 1):

Sorry because I don't have enough repulation to comment.
To close the app, you could use:

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

Comment: Is that a function for Java or JavaScript?

Comment: It's a function from Cordova

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle obj)
{
super.onCreate(obj)
setContextView(layout);

if (isOnline())
    //do your task 
else
    {
    try {
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(con).create();

alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available,try again later.");
alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     finish();

   }
});

alertDialog.show();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Show Dialog: "+e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But I'm developing my app in HTML & Javascript, not Java.. And I guess this is Java code